# Converting exponential LaTeX syntax to PHP's pow() using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, latex

I would like to use JS to convert a nested exponential LaTeX expression such as

```
2^{3^{4^5}}
```

to PHP's `pow()` syntax

```
pow(2,pow(3,pow(4,5)))
```

I know JS doesn't support recursive RegExp. The expression is part of an equation, so I expect the solution to work with something like

```
\frac{3}{9}+\frac{2^{\sqrt{4^2}}}{6}
```

which should output

```
\frac{3}{9}+\frac{pow(2,\sqrt{pow(4,2)})}{6}
```

like in @AbcAeffchen's solution.

*I don't need conversion for the non-exponential parts.*

*Notice*: The solution must not require resorting to PHP 5.6, which introduced the `**` operator

Comment: try this http://regex101.com/r/vL4kQ1/2, not perfect, also require looping

Comment: Please provide examples of possible inputs and their respective outputs. The 1 example you give is invalid.

Comment: If you mean the parentheses instead of curly braces, it is just for convenience. I have replaced with curly braces, Also added the desired output based on @AbcAeffchen solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function I wrote. It just uses ordinary string functions, so it is a little bit longer.
Basically it works as the following

- find the first occurrence of `^`
- find the part before `^` that belongs to the basis
- find the part after `^` that belongs to the exponent
- call the function recursive on the exponent and on the part after the exponent
- put all parts together.

and so it looks in JavaScript:

```js
function convertLatexPow(str)
{
    // contains no pow
    var posOfPow = str.indexOf('^');
    if(posOfPow == -1)
        return str;

    var head = str.substr(0,posOfPow);
    var tail = str.substr(posOfPow+1);

    // find the beginning of pow
    var headLen = posOfPow;
    var beginning = 0;
    var counter;
    if(head[headLen-1] == '}')      // find the opening brace
    {
        counter = 1;
        for(i = headLen-2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(head[i] == '}')
                counter++;
            else if(head[i] == '{')
                counter--;

            if(counter == 0)
            {
                beginning = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(head[headLen-1].match('[0-9]{1}'))  // find the beginning of the number
    {
        for(i = headLen-2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(!head[i].match('[0-9]{1}'))
            {
                beginning = i+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else    // the string looks like ...abc^{..}.. so the basis is only one character ('c' in this case)
        beginning = headLen-1;

    var untouchedHead = head.substr(0,beginning);

    var firstArg = head.substr(beginning);
    // find the end of pow
    var secondArg, untouchedTail;
    if(tail[0] != '{')
    {
        secondArg = tail[0];
        untouchedTail = tail.substr(1);
    }
    else
    {
        counter = 1;
        var len = tail.length;
        var end = len+1;
        for(i = 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            if(tail[i] == '{')
                counter++;
            else if(tail[i] == '}')
                counter--;

            if(counter == 0)
            {
                end = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        secondArg = tail.substr(1,end-1);
        if(end < len-1)
            untouchedTail = tail.substr(end+1);
        else
            untouchedTail = '';
    }

    return untouchedHead
        + 'pow(' + firstArg + ',' + convertLatexPow(secondArg) + ')'
        + convertLatexPow(untouchedTail);
}

alert(convertLatexPow('2^{3^{4^5}}'));
alert(convertLatexPow('\\frac{3}{9}+\\frac{2^{\\sqrt{4^2}}}{6}'));
alert(convertLatexPow('{a + 2 \\cdot (b + c)}^2'));
```

Input: `'2^{3^{4^5}}'`
Output: `pow(2,pow(3,pow(4,5)))`

Input: `'\\frac{3}{9}+\\frac{2^{\\sqrt{4^2}}}{6}'`
Output: `\frac{3}{9}+\frac{pow(2,\sqrt{pow(4,2)})}{6}`

Input: `'{a + 2 \\cdot (b + c)}^2'`
Output: `pow({a + 2 \cdot (b + c)},2)`

*Notice*: It do not parse the `\sqrt`. you have to do this extra.

Feel free to improve it :)

*Notice*: `^` in LaTeX does not mean *power*. It just means superscript. So `2^3` becomes 2<sup>3</sup> (and looks like "2 to the power of 3"), but `\sum_{i=1}^n` just becomes better formatted. But you can extend the function above to ignore `^` directly after `}`.

*Notice*: As Lucas Trzesniewski mentioned in the comment, `2^3^4` is not converted "correct", but it is also not a valid LaTeX expression.

**Edit**: Improved the function to convert `'{a + 2 \\cdot (b + c)}^2'` right.

*Notice*: In LaTeX exists many ways to write a brace (e.g. `(`, `\left(`, `[`, `\lbrace`,..).
To be sure this function works fine with all this braces you should convert all that braces to `{` and `}` first. Or to normal braces `(`, but then the function has to be edited to look for `(` instead of `{`.

*Notice*: The complexity of this function is `O(n⋅k)`, where `n` is the length of the input and `k` is the number of `^` in the input. An worst case input would be the first test case `2^{3^{4^{...}}}`. But in most cases the function will be much faster. Something about `O(n)`.

Comment: `convertLatexPow("a^b^c")` outputs `pow(a,b)pow(,c)`. I guess the expected output is `pow(a, pow(b, c))` as `^` should be right-associative.

Comment: I know this issue, but it is not valid latex code, so i ignored it

Comment: Ok, I don't know latex so sorry about that. +1 for the non-regex solution then, as it's impossible to get this right with JavaScript regex syntax (ie. without recursion or balancing groups).

Comment: No problem, I added a notice to my answer

Answer (score 4):

An ugly hack,

```
> foo
'2,(3^(4^5))'
> var foo = "2^(3^(4^5))".replace(/\^/g, ",");
undefined
> foo
'2,(3,(4,5))'
> var bar = foo.replace(/(\d,)(?=[^\d])/g, "$1pow");
undefined
> var foobar = bar.replace(/^(.*)$/, "pow($1)")
undefined
> foobar
'pow(2,pow(3,pow(4,5)))'
```

Comment: It works on an isolated expression, but not on a whole equation where the exponential expression is embedded, e.g. `\frac{3}{9}+\frac{2^{\sqrt{4^2}}}{6}`

Comment: @Avinash gave you what you asked for, what you said requires a complete converter from all latex commands to php functions

Comment: @Matanya Do you expect `\frac{3}{9}+\frac{2^{\sqrt{4^2}}}{6}` to be `frac(3,9)+frac(pow(2,sqrt(pow(4,2))),6)` ? [functions mapping needs to be defined by you]

Comment: I am NOT looking for a complete converter. Only interested in the exponential expression. The downside to @AvinashRaj solution is that it only works on isolated exponential expression, thus my example, which yields using the aforementioned solution `pow(\frac{3}{9}+\frac{2,pow{\sqrt{4,2}}}{6})`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it iteratively:

```
var foo = "2^(3^(4^5))";
while (/\([^^]+\^[^^]+\)/.test(foo)) {
  foo = foo.replace(/\(([^^]+)\^([^^]+)\)/, "pow($1,$2)");
}
if (/(.+)\^(.+)/.test(foo)) {
  foo = "pow(" + RegExp.$1 + "," + RegExp.$2 + ")";
}
# foo == "pow(2,pow(3,pow(4,5)))"
```